# How to make a Python HTTP server where I can download files of a directory

Tags: python

I'm searching for Python Script where I can make a hTTP Server, that allows to download the files of a specific folder (Linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the command:

`python -m http.server 8180`